# Delete an object inside of array with firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query the specific object by the property "id" inside the array and remove/delete the whole object. Is this possible through firestore?

**My firestore structure looks like this:**

[image]

For now I have function called `removeCard()` that takes in the docId which is the document id in firestore, and the cardId which is property "id" value inside the object.

**removeCard() function:**

```
export const removeCard = (retroId, cardId) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
    // make async call to database
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    firestore.collection('retros').doc(retroId).update({
      // firestore query to remove/delete this card.
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_CARD_SUCCESS' });
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_CARD_ERROR' }, err);
    });
  }
};
```

But I cant figure out how to do this query or if it's even possible to do with Firestore. Any help is appreciated. Just tell me if i should provide with any more information to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, at the time of writing, it is not possible, with `array-contains`, to query for a specific property of an object stored in an array.

A possible workaround exists, which is to query **for the entire object**.

In your case it would be like

```
db.collection('retros').where("cardsAction", "array-contains", {id: "65....", content: "this is...", time: ....})
```

but obviously this workaround will not be useful in your case as both the `time` and `content` values may vary.

So in other words, you will probably need to change your data model.

One possible approach would be to duplicate your data (quite common in NoSQL world) and have another array with only the `ids` of the `cardAction`, like:

```
cardActionIds = ["65....", "5789", ....]
```

This way you can use `array-contains` and once you have found the docs corresponding to the `cardActionIds` you manipulate the other array (i.e. `cardAction`)

Comment: That's what I expected.. Would be nice if google could make this possible in the future. Do you have any ideas how I could change my data model to make it work? Thanks btw, for the answer!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you put this data in an array apart from having  a container for a collection of data? Do you use the array in the front end  for example, displaying the entire list of cardsAction?

Comment: I've added a possible approach in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at it. Cheers mate.